# Python subprocess: return value incorrect

Tags: python, subprocess, shlex

I am writing a Python module which uses subprocess, to both see if a process has ran and also to get its PID. So far I have done the part of running processes.

The processes clearly run, but there is something wrong with this code so it throws my custom exception ReturnFalseValue.

```
def sys_userwrapper(user, cmd):
    cmd = "su " + user + " --login --command=\"" + cmd + "\""
    dbgPrint("running: " + cmd)
    args = shlex.split(cmd)

    p = subprocess.Popen(args)
    p.wait()
    r = p.returncode

    if (not p == 0):
        raise ReturnValueFalse
    else:
        return p.pid
```

Here is my little unit test of the method...

```
>>> relayman.sys_userwrapper("oper", "echo helloworld")
Debug: running: su oper --login --command="echo helloworld"
helloworld
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/root/relayman.py", line 32, in sys_userwrapper
    raise ReturnValueFalse
relayman.ReturnValueFalse
```

As you can see it prints the HelloWorld, yet for some reason it thinks there was an error as if echo didn't return 0 yet did work.

Comment: Don't you want to check `r`, not `p`?

Comment: It should get "r" from "p" I thought, what I do it not have that and just have "r"?

Answer (score 4):

`r` holds your return code; you tested `if (not p == 0):`, where `p` is the `Popen` object. `Popen` objects definitely aren't equal to zero.

Comment: Will make this the correct answer after the timer (7mins as of posting)